# ad8426 instrumental amplifier design

Tags: instrumentation-amplifier, single-supply-op-amp, virtual-ground

I'm having a problem with my AD8426 instrumental amplifier design. As I show in the image, I use a 3.3 V supply and after increasing my input signal, I use 1.8V virtual ground to make it oscillate on 1.8 V. However, since Vout oscillates above 1.7395 V, the next stage increases the voltage difference between Opamp 1.8 and 1.7395. Since this does not comply with the operating conditions of the LTC 2068, I see a flat output above 3.29 at the opamp output. I solved the problem experimentally by putting a capacitor (C17) at the inamp output, but I do not know how accurate this will be in an EEG application.

Is there a way to overlay the AD8426 output to exactly 1.8 V? Or the method I applied (placing a capacitor C17) is okay?

- First picture shows the circuit
- Second picture shows the output without a capacitor ( C17 )
- Third picture shows the output with capacitor C17

[![the circuit][1]][1]

[image: the output without a capacitor ( C17 )]

[image: the output with capacitor C17]

Comment: The screenshot of the simulation is cutted on the left side, so no one is knowing what's happening there.

Comment: @Daniel can you now check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please review what I have drawn below: -

[image]

In red you have biased the output section of the Instrumentation amplifier correctly but, it doesn't do anything to bias the inputs so, in orange you have inputs biased at 0 volts via R3 and R4. The result is that AC signals superimposed on inputs biased at 0 volts can damage the device and, for sure, make it not-work as intended.

Comment: thank you @andy aka your feedback helped me out

Comment: @atıfkoçak if we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Comment: with the help of your response I dropped the resistor values and calculated new capacitance values. It solved my problem but I don't know whether the low resistor values cause any further problems in real applications. Do you have any observation to share with me?

Comment: Are you talking about C4, C5, R3 and R4? You do need to apply a positive offset voltage the the InAmp inputs to ensure that the signals on them do not go below ground/0 volts.